Canvas panel appears black in WPF
I have developed software that includes drawing in WPF MVVM pattern. I Used canvas panel as ItemControls item template. The software works but in one computer the canvas panel appears black.
I checked the graphics card software. It is up to date.
I checked the framework version. It is update.
These are XAML codes.
 <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        BorderThickness="0.5"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        x:Name="ItemsControl" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes, IsAsync=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
     <ItemsControl.Resources >

         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:TextNode}">
             <TextBlock x:Name="txtBox" Text="{Binding Text,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        RenderTransform="{Binding Transform}"
                        FontSize="{Binding FontSize}"
                        Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"/>

         </DataTemplate>

         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:GeometryNode}">
             <Path Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" 
                   StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"
                   Fill="{Binding Gradient}"
                   Opacity="{Binding Opacity}"
                   RenderTransform="{Binding Transform}"
                   Data="{Binding Geometri}"/>
        </DataTemplate>


     </ItemsControl.Resources>
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas"
                     ClipToBounds="True"
                     Focusable="True"/>

         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=XPos}" />
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=YPos}" />
         </Style>
     </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>


 </ItemsControl>

The software normally looks like this

One computer looks like this. Canvas panel is black.

Framework version information of the relevant computer

Does anyone have any ideas on this? I've been trying to figure it out for a few days but I can't figure it out.

Where do your brushes and colours for them come from?  Might be related to chosen theme or os or maybe the expected resource isn't where it's supposed to be.

@Andy OS is Windows 11. Do you mean Windows themes?
